# PyInstaller: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I had successfully compiled my script: main.py using PyInstaller. However when I tried to run the main.exe application under dist/main directory, I got the below error:

```html
C:\test\trunk\testalgorithm\testengine\dist\main>main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testengine\main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\users\bot\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\Py
Installer\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "testengine\K.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\users\bot\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\Py
Installer\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "testengine\backend\data_retrieval.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\users\bot\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\Py
Installer\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "alertsengine\backend\log_config.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1008, in __init__
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\test\\trunk\\testalgorithm\\testengine\\dist\\main\\logs\\LOG_17_07_05_24_2017.log'
Failed to execute script main
```

I dont know what it means by there's no log files.

Did I miss something? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6):

You might want to edit your spec file.
After running `pyinstaller main.py`, go to the main folder and add your log folder as Data Files to your main.spec file. It should look, in your case, something like this:

```
added_files = [
         ( './logs', 'logs' )
         ]

a = Analysis(...
     datas=added_files,
     ...
     )
```

After that, run `pyinstaller main.spec` to redistribute your app.

Note that you'd probably have to have more add data files after that. You may read more [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-data-files)

Comment: I did it but I am getting the same error. In my case I am trying to create a standalone app using MacOS for a Tkinter Python script. I am trying to include .jpg and .png files used in Tk windows. I got success creating it without the .jpg and .png though.

Comment: In my case I also had to make sure to use the absolute path when referencing an added file using `path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'myfile.txt')` [see the docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file)